# Why does Ruby not throw an error in an instance where the class name and file name of the class are mismatched?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, autoload

Why isn't the Ruby interpreter throwing a NameError in this instance here?

```
class OrangeTurtle
   self.table_name = 'turtles'
end
```

Filename: orange_turtles.rb

Comment: Not familiar with any languages that enforce this behavior.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Why would Ruby `raise` a `NameError` in this case? The only reason it could `raise` a `NameError` is if `Class#table_name` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

This answer might sound like a cop out, but it doesn't throw an error because Ruby doesn't care even the slightest what your filenames are called.

e.g. in file `asdfasdf.no_rb_ending_here` we can have

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
module Something
  class Test
    def test
      puts 'test'
    end
  end
end
class SomethingElse
  def otherThings
    puts 'haha'
  end
end
```

Then to make things even weirder, I can have a separate file that modifies (monkey patches) the classes defined in that file.
in `more_stuff.rb`

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require_relative 'asdfasdf.no_rb_ending_here'
module Something
  class Test
    def test2
      test()
      puts '2'
    end
  end
end
class SomethingElse
  def moreThings
    otherThings()
    puts 'MOAR'
  end
end

Something::Test.new.test2()
# test
# 2
SomethingElse.new.moreThings()
# haha
# MOAR
```

Ruby is pretty cool - you don't get errors for things that don't NEED to cause an error.

Answer (score 0):

The name error, or uninitialized constant error only appears in Rails. The reason for that is, that active record (which is also a general design pattern) is mapping the tables in the database with the models (or with objects in general).
Active Record can only make that connection via the naming conventions for files and the classes.
As mentioned in the other answer, pure ruby doesn't need to comply with these conventions. However, it is a general rule to name the files like the classes they contain to have better organised code.